# if achieved, wait for next command

Tags: c#

I am trying to achieve a function where my bot will

1. Wait for first function to be true but does not execute yet but just triggers it to begin waiting
2. Waits for second to be true and then executes
3. Executes whether or not the first is true or false still at it was achieved previously

At this point I can only get it to execute if both are still true.

I currently have it written as:

if (rsi.Result.LastValue < LRL && Bars.ClosePrices[index] > EnterAndExitMA.Result[index])
Open(TradeType.Buy);

but I know that the && makes it require both to be achieved at the same time.. I am not sure how to convert that to the steps above.

```
    using System;
using System.Linq;
using cAlgo.API;
using cAlgo.API.Indicators;
using cAlgo.API.Internals;
using cAlgo.Indicators;

namespace cAlgo
{
    [Robot(TimeZone = TimeZones.UTC, AccessRights = AccessRights.None)]
    public class OversoldOverboughtMACross : Robot
    {
        [Parameter("Quantity (Lots)", Group = "Volume", DefaultValue = 1, MinValue = 0.01, Step = 0.01)]
        public double Quantity { get; set; }

        [Parameter("Source", Group = "RSI")]
        public DataSeries Source { get; set; }

        [Parameter("Label", DefaultValue = "MAType")]
        public string Label { get; set; }

        [Parameter("MA Type")]
        public MovingAverageType MAType { get; set; }

        [Parameter("Enter And Exit Period", DefaultValue = 55)]
        public int EnterAndExitPeriod { get; set; }

        [Parameter("Periods", Group = "RSI", DefaultValue = 55)]
        public int Periods { get; set; }

        [Parameter("Lower RSI Level", Group = "RSI", DefaultValue = 35, MinValue = 0, MaxValue = 50)]
        public int LRL { get; set; }

        [Parameter("Upper RSI Level", Group = "RSI", DefaultValue = 65, MinValue = 50, MaxValue = 100)]
        public int URL { get; set; }


        private RelativeStrengthIndex rsi;
        private MovingAverage EnterAndExitMA;

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            rsi = Indicators.RelativeStrengthIndex(Source, Periods);
            EnterAndExitMA = Indicators.MovingAverage(Source, EnterAndExitPeriod, MAType);
        }

        protected override void OnBar()
        {
            int index = Bars.Count - 2;
            Exit(index);

            {
                {
                    if (rsi.Result.LastValue < LRL && Bars.ClosePrices[index] > EnterAndExitMA.Result[index])
                        Open(TradeType.Buy);
                    else if (rsi.Result.LastValue > URL && Bars.ClosePrices[index] < EnterAndExitMA.Result[index])
                        Open(TradeType.Sell);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Open(TradeType tradeType)
        {
            var position = Positions.Find(Label, SymbolName, tradeType);
            var volumeInUnits = Symbol.QuantityToVolumeInUnits(Quantity);

            if (position == null)
                ExecuteMarketOrder(tradeType, SymbolName, volumeInUnits, Label, null, null);
        }

        private void Exit(int index)
        {
            var positions = Positions.FindAll(Label);

            foreach (var position in positions)

                if ((position.TradeType == TradeType.Buy && rsi.Result.LastValue > URL && Bars.ClosePrices[index] < EnterAndExitMA.Result[index]) || (position.TradeType == TradeType.Sell && rsi.Result.LastValue < LRL && Bars.ClosePrices[index] > EnterAndExitMA.Result[index]))

                    ClosePosition(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we need a bit more code; specifically the minimum amount of code necessary for this to compile.

Comment: Can you help me understand what this statement means?  "Wait for first function to be true but does not execute yet but just triggers it to begin waiting"  If you don't execute it, why wait on it?  If you don't execute it, how can it ever be true?

Comment: 1. RSI must be below 35 to give a signal ...
2. Waits for confirmation of price crossing above the Moving Average to enter a trade ...
3. The RSI, many times does not display it being below 35 anymore by the time price crosses above the Moving Average ....

I do not wish to execute everytime price crosses the Moving Average... only the first cross after the RSI has given a signal